# hide software keyboard after resume from another app

Tags: android, hide, android-activity, android-softkeyboard

My app sends data to other apps. Some times the other app opens a soft keyboard, but does not close it. Problem is, that after the resume to my app I am unable to close that sofware keyboard like in normal cases within my app:

```
((InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)).hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

I also tried view.getApplicationWindowToken() and various flags with no success. How can I close a soft keyboard, which was opened by a different app?

Answer (score 0):

This is just a guess, but can you do something like get the ActivityManager, find the last Activity that was run, then figure out it's Window Token?

I don't honestly know if that's possible, but hopefully it puts you down the right road.

Activity Manager Code (I know this is almost no help):

```
// get the ActivityManager
ActivityManager result = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
```

EDIT:

I should note that that's really not what the ActivityManager is there for... so it might end be being kind of a hack-y solution to dig into the windows of another activity...